# What's the appropriate built-in Exception to raise if your library is used with the wrong Python Version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, version

I have a simple library distributed as a .py file.  I would like to raise an exception if the library is called from Python 2 instead of Python 3:

```
def _check_version():
    if sys.version_info < (3,):
        raise _____Exception('This library depends on Python 3 strings. Please ensure you are using Python 3 instead of Python 2')
```

What built-in exception should I raise? (How do I fill in the blank above?) The closest exception I can find among the [builtin Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) is NotImplementedError. The DeprecationWarning feels close, but an exception is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: why would you want to raise an exception in this case instead of just exiting?

Comment: Raising an exception might help the user trace it back to the right library, or to some intermediate code that depends on the library.  Although that sounds highly unlikely in this case. I also want my students to get into the habit of raising exceptions instead of just exiting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) for this; there is no more specific exception.

Comment: I'd `raise RuntimeError("<pkg> needs Python 3.7 or later")` so that the stderr both gives information and can be parsed automatically/ logged, and makes it clear that the culprit is *<pkg>* not some other package or Python itself, which would not be clear to non-Python users; having had to write production scripts that get used by non-Python users.

Answer (score 2):

`raise RuntimeError("<pkg> needs Python 3.7 or later")`

- so that the stderr both gives information and can be parsed automatically/ logged
- and makes it clear that the culprit is *`<pkg>`* not some other package or Python itself, which would not be clear to non-Python users; having had to write production scripts that get used by non-Python users. Don't expect non-Python users to read or understand Python tracebacks.